# What are attractions at fair called, where you buy food?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, british-english

What are the houses called where you can buy food at fairs? Like the shops, are they called *stalls*?
And what are other attractions in a fair called? Is *fair* even the right word or is *adventure park* more accurate?

Comment: Fairs and adventure parks are different things, which one are you talking about?

Comment: The one, where you can buy almonds, win plush animals, go to ghost houses and ride rollercoasters. Which one is it and where is the difference?

Comment: In America, they're called "amusement parks" and there are a lot of them. It's a big country. Google maps will be happy to find "amusement parks near me" on your phone. Plus there are small moving ones called "carnivals" which set up for special occasions in parking lots or vacant fields, especially in the summer.

Comment: I would probably say "vendors".

Comment: Sometimes they are just foodtrucks all lined up in a row. https://images.app.goo.gl/knuzWRJhzJ7GmHEs8

Comment: In American English, those are known as concession stands or just *concessions*. Other attractions might include *rides* (e.g. a roller coaster) and *booths* (e.g. get your tattoo here).

Comment: The places where you win the animals and whatnot are sometimes called "booths".

Comment: Although some of the answers to the other question can also serve as answers to this one, the question itself is hardly a duplicate of that other question: there is a difference between something like that being on the side of the road and being within a fair, and that may affect the acceptability of some answers. Voting to close something as a duplicate should be based on what the questions are: different questions can have the same answers and still be different questions.

Comment: @jsw29: I agree. We can vote to reopen. Alas, the closing and reopening system does not work properly on many SE sites: it now takes only three people to close something, and reopening is absolutely unfeasible 99% of the time because simply too few people ever see questions that aren't new.

Answer (score 3):

1. Concession Stand: noun US A stall or booth, typically selling food or inexpensive items, and operating within a larger business or commercial area. ([Source - Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/concession_stand))
2. A fair is a gathering of people to display or trade produce or other goods, to parade or display animals and often to enjoy associated "carnival or funfair entertainment." It is normally of the essence of a fair that it is temporary; some last only an afternoon while others may last as long as ten weeks. ([Source - definitions.net](https://www.definitions.net/definition/FAIR)).
3. Amusement Parks are permanent installations.

Comment: @jsw29: I've added the source.

Comment: @justin Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I would say you can use **stand, stall**, or **booth**, also depending on what an attraction is like, exactly.

For example, I would probably expect a booth to have side walls/panels between which you stand, but perhaps a stall might not. The distinction is very slight and certainly not consistent: the words are mostly synonymous in the context of a fair, I think.

The word I'd probably use is *stand* but any of them would seem fine to me. Shooting you might also do at a *gallery*. A place where you sit in a moving seat may be called a *ride*.

You can see usage examples of all three words when you [Google them](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+fair%22+%22the+shooting+stand%7Cstall%7Cbooth%22).

The Wikipedia article on *[carnival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_carnival)* also seems to use all three words.

Comment: In the U.S., the term "food kiosks" is sometimes used, as well.